# Install and activate Android SDK to work on RAD Studio 11

Tags: android, sdk

Hi I install RAD studio 11 and select all die SDK to install as well, when I check the platforms it show that Delphi iOS Enterprise and Delphi Android Enterprise is installed.

How do I get to start creating Android and iOS apps because all the docs from Embarcadero are for other versions and nothing for Delphi 11.

Where do I get the SDK manager to setup my Andriod device on USB?

All that tI can find is under Tools -> Options

- Under Deployment -> SDK Manager, but there I are SDK versions Android SDK 25.2.5 64-bit and Android SDK 25.2.5 32-bit

When I try to add and point to the suggested folder , when I go to next Ican't find the Delphi NDK Library path to finish the setup